# Custom field on Lead and contact Validation Rules

Tags: acumatica

Lead and contact validation rules (CR101000) not shows all fields in matching field property. I want to add rule on custom field

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, Lead and Contact Validation Rules can only be defined with the base Contact DAC fields decorated with the PXMassMergableField attribute. No option currency available to extend the list of fields to specify Validation Rules.